# Run Java Swing UI inside ActiveX Browser object

Tags: java, swing, activex

We have a "desktop" application written in Java Swing that currently uses Java Web Start to instantiate the app.

We have a need to run this application INSIDE an ActiveX Browser object.

Does anyone know if this is possible and, if so, how it could be done?

Thank you!

EDIT: is there any more information I could offer that might make this question more answerable?

Comment: well, i can't tell you _how_ to do it, but at one point in time, it could be done.  a loooong time ago, back when microsoft supported java, i used visual studio (6 i believe) to do this very thing.  can't tell you if it is _still_ possible, though (or how exactly i did it, visual studio did a whole lot of magic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Java ignorance is showing. It appears that starting in v6 you can run Swing Applications in a Java Applet inside a browser using the same basic jnlp setup (with minor changes) as the Web Start method. There are some security issues I have to work out moving to support v6, but once that is fixed we should be in business!

Answer (score 0):

You can try compiling the application with [iKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/), basically making it a .NET application which should be able to run within an ActiveX component.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'll keep ikvm in mind. It appears for the immediate concern, however, that ikvm does not support Swing (http://weblog.ikvm.net/PermaLink.aspx?guid=75a5b8a3-7605-4f6f-a466-8d6c4632f7e3)

Comment: It might be a bit risky, but swing might work, the page you mentioned says: "Not supported." means that the code is there and probably works at least somewhat, but that I'm less likely to fix bugs reported in these areas.

Comment: On the other hand, eclipse has been reported to run under IKVM, and it indeed uses swing.